# Heaviside step function composed with a function

Tags: integration, special-functions, function-and-relation-composition

I am trying to solve the following equation
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Theta(g(\tau))f(\tau)d\tau$$
with $\Theta(t)$ being the heaviside step function defined by:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\Theta (t) =0, t<0
\\ 
\Theta (t) =1, t\geq 0
\end{matrix}\right. $$
and $g(t)$ a continuously differentiable function and $f(t)$ a test function.

Knowing the link between the Heaviside and the Dirac functions, I was wondering if we could get to the same kind of property as for the Dirac in this case:
 $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta (g(\tau))f(\tau)d\tau = \sum_{i} \frac{f(x_{i})}{\left | g'(x_{i}) \right |}. $$

Or if you have any other idea of how to solve it, it would be great!

Comment: Hint: decompose $g(\tau)$ into intervals where it is positive or negative. Then apply the defintion of the Heaviside function.