# President Obama proposed the elimination of taxes on dividends paid to shareholders on the grounds that they result in double taxation.

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

President Obama proposed the elimination of taxes on dividends paid to shareholders on the grounds that they result in double taxation. The earnings used to pay dividends are already taxed to the corporation. A survey by Dr Greg on this issue revealed that 47% of Americans favor the proposal. By political party, 64% of the democrats and 29% of the Republicans favor the proposal. Suppose a group of 250 Americans gather to hear a speech about the proposal.
What is the probability that at least half of the group is in favor of the proposal?

Attempt:

I tried solving it Using normal approximation to binomial but I'm not sure
The survey is a Bernouilli trial (yes/no, heads/tails, in favour of/against) so the binomial distribution applies.
The mean is np=250*0.47=117.5 and the standard deviation is s=sqrt(npq)=7.9.

I can't continue from here

Comment: Why the downvotes please?

Comment: If you track enough of the votes, you might use the normal distribution to estimate the percentage of MSE users in favor of doing your homework. ;)

Comment: Comment of the day @Titus!

Comment: You've stopped at an early stage of the problem, and the remaining steps can be found in textbooks and online, in plenty of places.  A quick googling gave this for example:  http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/ats7/blesson3.htm
You should read the whole page to start to see the process and make sure you understand it!  Return with specific questions if you have them.

Comment: No. It's not my homework. My examinations starts next two weeks so I'm solving previous years questions. As many as I see, so I got lost in this. Its not my homework. I'm not in high school.

Comment: Comment of the year @Titus!

Comment: I fail to see how the piece of data about "political distribution" has any impact on the probability at hand whatsoever.

Comment: `By political party, 64% of the democrats and 29% of the Republicans favor the proposal.`

Does that sentence contribute to the answer at all? I thought you only needed the 47%..

Comment: The downvotes and upvotes on questions are not always logical. For example here (link). The questioner has shown no effort, but the question got an upvote. There a many other examples. Your question probably needs an integral or should be about group theory.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470060/heaviside-step-function-composed-with-a-function

Comment: Yeah. The political party should be disregarded since its of no use.

Comment: @user274246 Did the answer help ?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. But I don't know you got the 0.5.

Comment: Is there a formula for the continuity correction factor?

Comment: @user274246 No, there is **no formula for** the continuity correction, it is always 0.5. It is **part of the formula**. There is a nice animation which shows the influence of the continuity factor. Just move the mouse over the red (animated) graph. If the x values of the normal distribution goes 0.5 to the right, then there is a match with the binomial distribution. I have to admit, that the site is in german, but this animation is really helpful:  http://www.matheprisma.uni-wuppertal.de/Module/Hypoth/Herleitung.htm

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. One more thing, the formula you used. Can you give me the format because you already inserted the values so I don't know what they stand for. Its different from the normal distribution formula I know.

Comment: @user274246 Not really. Only the correction factor. I have made an edit of my answer. Please begin the next comment with (at)calclulus. Then I get a message from the system, that you have made a comment. Or make the comment right below my answer.

Comment: The assumption would have to be that this  "group of $250$ Americans" is a random sample from the whole population.  Getting them all to gather in one place is not going to be easy.  If you chose people in a single geographical area, the probabilities would be much different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $Let X\sim Bin(250,0.47)$

$$P(X\geq 125)=1-P(X\leq 124)\approx 1-\Phi\left( \frac{x+0.5-\mu}{\sigma} \right)=1-\Phi\left( \frac{x+0.5-n\cdot p}{\sqrt{n\cdot p\cdot (1-p)}} \right)$$

$$= 1-\Phi\left( \frac{124+0.5-0.47\cdot 250}{\sqrt{250\cdot 0.47\cdot (1-0.47)}} \right)$$

$\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution. 0.5 is the continuity correction factor.

Comment: Hello, can you reply please?

Comment: Alright. Thank you. I got 17.2% as the final answer. Is that right?

Comment: @user274246 I got $1-\Phi(0.887)=1-0.8125=0.1875=18.75\%$. For the value of $\Phi(0.887)$ I used a calculator. If I use the table, then I get  $1-\Phi(0.89)=1-0.81327=0.1867=18.67\%$. The link for table I used is https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf And the calculation of the value z can be seen here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B124%2B0.5-0.47%5Ccdot+250%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B250%5Ccdot+0.47%5Ccdot+%281-0.47%29%7D%7D+ I do not know from where the little difference come from.

Comment: Oh, I've seen my mistake. Thanks a lot. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @user274246 Nice, that it works. You´re welcome.