# Integral of Heaviside composed with a circular function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**Context**

In [1] there is a related question that remains unanswered.

**Question**

Let $-1 \leq x  \leq 1$,  $0 \leq \beta \leq \pi$, and $H$ be the Heaviside step function. Given than 
\begin{align*}
f(x) 
&= 
\int_{0}^{2\,\pi } 
\left[  H\left(x + \left| \cos\left( \phi + \beta\right) \right|
\right) -  H\left(x - \left| \cos\left(\phi  + \beta\right) \right|
\right) \right]     d\phi,   
\end{align*}
What is a closed-form analytic expression for $f(x)$?

**Solution**

> $$f(x) = 
> 4\,\cos^{-1}{\left( \left|x\right| \right)}.  $$

**Derivation**

Substitution: $\alpha = \phi +\beta$
\begin{align*}
f(x) 
&= 
\int_{\beta}^{2\,\pi+\beta } 
\left[  H\left(x + \left| \cos\left( \alpha\right) \right|
\right) -  H\left(x - \left| \cos\left(\alpha\right) \right|
\right) \right]     d\alpha,   
\end{align*}
From properties of integrals with $\cos$ integrand.
\begin{align*}
f(x) 
&= 
\int_{0}^{2\,\pi} 
\left[  H\left(x + \left| \cos\left( \alpha\right) \right|
\right) -  H\left(x - \left| \cos\left(\alpha\right) \right|
\right) \right]     d\alpha,   
\end{align*}
From periodicity of the $\cos$ with the absolute value.
\begin{align*}
f(x) 
&= 
2\,\int_{0}^{ \pi} 
\left[  H\left(x + \left| \cos\left( \alpha\right) \right|
\right) -  H\left(x - \left| \cos\left(\alpha\right) \right|
\right) \right]     d\alpha,   
\end{align*}
From reflection properties of the $\cos$.
\begin{align*}
f(x) 
&= 
4\,\int_{0}^{ \pi/2} 
\left[  H\left(x + \left| \cos\left( \alpha\right) \right|
\right) -  H\left(x - \left| \cos\left(\alpha\right) \right|
\right) \right]     d\alpha,   
\end{align*}
Considering that we have a boxcar function [2], the integral will yield area between
$0\leq \alpha\leq  \cos^{-1}{\left(\left|x\right|\right)} \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.
Since the integrand is the unit one when the integral yields area, I find that 
\begin{align*}
f(x) 
&= 
4\,\left[\cos^{-1}{\left( \left|x\right| \right)}-0\right] 
\end{align*}

**Bibliography**

[1] [Heaviside step function composed with a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470060/heaviside-step-function-composed-with-a-function)

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function

Comment: You wrote $1\le x \le 1$... there are not so many $x$ left. And also what is $\phi$???  Can you take the time to revisit your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is closed

$$f(x) = 
4\,\cos^{-1}{\left(\left|x\right|\right)}.  $$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we can simplify everything greatly by using the substitution $\alpha=\phi+\beta,$ to transform the integral to
$$f(x) = \int_{\beta}^{2\pi+\beta } 
\left[  H\left(x + \left| \cos\left( \alpha\right) \right|
\right) -  H\left(x - \left| \cos\left(\alpha\right) \right|
\right) \right]     d\alpha $$
Let
$$g(\alpha)=H\left(x + \left| \cos\left( \alpha\right) \right|
\right) -  H\left(x - \left| \cos\left(\alpha\right) \right|
\right) $$
and
$$C_\beta=[\beta,2\pi+\beta]. $$
This is a square function of $\alpha,$ which I will rewrite as follows:
$$g(\alpha)=\begin{cases}
0,&x<-|\cos(\alpha)|\\
1,&-|\cos(\alpha)|<x<|\cos(\alpha)|\\
0,&|\cos(\alpha)|<x, \end{cases} $$
or more simply
$$g(\alpha)=\begin{cases}
0,&|x|>|\cos(\alpha)|\\
1,&|x|<|\cos(\alpha)|.
\end{cases} $$
I am not going to be rigorous about the transition points, because under an integral sign they don't matter. We need to solve the conditions for $\alpha$ to make the integral more manageable. The condition $|x|<|\cos(\alpha)|$ we can write as follows:
\begin{align*}
x&<\cos(\alpha),\;x>0,\;\cos(\alpha)>0\\
x&>-\cos(\alpha),\;x<0,\;\cos(\alpha)>0\\
x&>\cos(\alpha),\;x<0,\;\cos(\alpha)<0\\
x&<-\cos(\alpha),\;x>0,\;\cos(\alpha)<0,
\end{align*}
which becomes
\begin{align*}
x&<\cos(\alpha),\;x>0,\;\cos(\alpha)>0\\
-x&<\cos(\alpha),\;x<0,\;\cos(\alpha)>0\\
x&>\cos(\alpha),\;x<0,\;\cos(\alpha)<0\\
-x&>\cos(\alpha),\;x>0,\;\cos(\alpha)<0.
\end{align*}
This we can write more compactly as
\begin{align*}
|x|&<\cos(\alpha),\;\cos(\alpha)>0\\
-|x|&>\cos(\alpha),\;\cos(\alpha)<0.
\end{align*}
Now the $\arccos$ function on the interval $[-1,1]$ is a monotonically decreasing function. So when we apply it to both sides of an inequality, we must reverse the inequality. This yields
\begin{align*}
\arccos(|x|)&>\alpha,\;\cos(\alpha)>0\\
\arccos(-|x|)&<\alpha,\;\cos(\alpha)<0.
\end{align*}
We can further isolate the conditions for $\alpha$ by noting that, on the possible interval of $[0,3\pi],$ we have
\begin{align*}
\cos(\alpha)&> 0,\quad \alpha\in\underbrace{(0,\pi/2)\cup(3\pi/2,5\pi/2)}_{:=A} \\
\cos(\alpha)&< 0,\quad \alpha\in\underbrace{(\pi/2,3\pi/2)\cup(5\pi/2,3\pi)}_{:=B}.
\end{align*}
So we can rewrite $|x|<|\cos(\alpha)|$ as
\begin{align*}
\arccos(|x|)&>\alpha,\;\alpha\in A\\
\arccos(-|x|)&<\alpha,\;\alpha\in B.
\end{align*}
Similarly, the condition $|x|>|\cos(\alpha)|$ we can write
\begin{align*}
\arccos(|x|)&<\alpha,\;\alpha\in A\\
\arccos(-|x|)&>\alpha,\;\alpha\in B.
\end{align*}
The condition $|x|<|\cos(\alpha)|$ is where the integrand $g(\alpha)=1,$ which is the only condition under which we pick up area under the $\alpha$ integral.  Let us consider 
\begin{align*}
f(x)
=&\int_{A\cap C_\beta} \left[  H\left(x + \left| \cos\left( \alpha\right) \right|
\right) -  H\left(x - \left| \cos\left(\alpha\right) \right|
\right) \right]     d\alpha\\
+&\int_{B\cap C_\beta} \left[  H\left(x + \left| \cos\left( \alpha\right) \right|
\right) -  H\left(x - \left| \cos\left(\alpha\right) \right|
\right) \right]     d\alpha.
\end{align*}
We can rewrite this as
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\int_{A\cap C_\beta}g(\alpha)\,d\alpha+\int_{B\cap C_\beta}g(\alpha)\,d\alpha \\
&=m(\{\alpha\in A\cap C_\beta:\arccos(|x|)>\alpha\})+m(\{\alpha\in B\cap C_\beta:\arccos(-|x|)<\alpha\}).
\end{align*}
If you want to rewrite using original variables, you could say
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=m(\{\phi+\beta\in A\cap C_\beta:\arccos(|x|)>\phi+\beta\})\\
&+m(\{\phi+\beta\in B\cap C_\beta:\arccos(-|x|)<\phi+\beta\}). 
\end{align*}
Here I'm using the Lebesgue measure function $m;$ all you need to know here is that it measures intervals like this: $m((a,b))=b-a.$ That is, it just gives you the width of the intervals.

This is a closed-form expression for $f(x),$ although it still leaves calculation to be done. In particular, for any given $x$ and $\beta,$ you'd need to calculate $A\cap C_\beta$ and $B\cap C_\beta,$ as well as the locations where the conditions are met.

Comment: I suggest an improvement. As written $\alpha + \beta \in [0,3\pi]$. Since we are manipulating $cos^{-1}$ functions, I assert that it would be beneficial to state the solution from only the domain of the principal cut of $cos^{-1}$.